# How to perform a reverse lookup of the localized version of a string to it's original string

Tags: python, django, localization

I need to perform a lookup of the original string based on it's localized version in Django.

Is there a built in method for that (couldn't find it in the docs) or is there a smart way to achieve something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Looked through the sources and implemented a working solution:

```
from django.utils.translation.trans_real import catalog
def ugettextReversed(message):
    #flip translation catalog key, val
    catalogFlipped = dict((v,k) for k,v in catalog()._catalog.iteritems())
    if message in catalogFlipped:
        return catalogFlipped.get(message)
    else:
        return message
```